# Script EC2 Instance Launch Upon Purchase

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I need to script launching an EC2 instance and deploying Docker containers to said instance after a customer purchases a product from my site. I know that this is possible, but that it would require me to store my AWS credentials in the environment variables of my server. Are there any secure methods of establishing such a system?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: You can give your instance an [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) that would allow it to create more instances.  Usually, outside of development, storing AWS credentials as environment variables or in files isn't the best approach.

Comment: There are many ways of solving this problem. Most importantly, you should consider a queue and a rate limiting system first. Having a direct link between customer action and your AWS environment is a scalable, billable nightmare.